# Postgres: Out of memory

Tags: postgresql

I have 3GB ram assigned to VMBox. Doing similarity check on column of a table consisting of about 3885 entries, so in total 3885*3885 comparisons. But I get this error:

```
    [23636.611505] Out of memory: Kill process 987 (postgres) score 848 or sacrifice child
    [23636.612762] Killed process 987 (postgres) total-vm:5404836kB, anon-rss:2772756kB, file-rss:828kB
    server closed the connection unexpectedly
            This probably means the server terminated abnormally
            before of while processing the request
    The connection to the server was lost. Ateempting reset: Succeeded.
```

Still no idea why 15,093,225 comparisons cause "Out of memory" on 3gb ram. Any solutions?

Edit: I increased
    `Shared_buffers = from 128MB to 1000MB`
    `Working_mem  = from 4MB to 50MB`

But still same error.

Edit2: I did explain and same error. Cartesian, because I have to compare sentences that are imported in cells.

Comment: Could you show the actual query?

Comment: What's your `shared_buffers` and `work_mem` set to? Also, your server is misconfigured for PostgreSQL; you should disable the OOM killer. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/kernel-resources.html#LINUX-MEMORY-OVERCOMMIT

Comment: I did : sysctl -w kernel.shmmax=1073741824 and sysctl -w kernel.shmall=262144. Also tried to add oom score -1000. Still same errors. How can I see shared buffers and work mem?

Comment: check `postgresql.conf` parameters

Comment: `Shared_buffers = 128MB`
`Working_mem  = 4MB`

Comment: Can you add the complete query the output of `explain (verbose)` for your query? (**Not**, `explain (analyze)` as that would also fail)

Comment: Again same errors. Query is  `select a.docID, a.sentenceID, b.docID, b.sentenceID, cosine (a.tokenizedsentence, b.tokenizedsentence) from nlpdata a, nlpdata b;`

Comment: Don't add code in comments **edit** your question. Can you do a plain `explain select ...`?. Why are you doing a cross join (cartesian product) between the two tables? You are missing a join condition.

Comment: Hello @Masyaf, Could you please let me know If it is resolved

Comment: @M.S.Naidu hello, I have switched to dedicated server with a lot better hardware from virtual machine, so have not tried to to anything with it.

Comment: Okay Thank you @Masyaf